# Property injection on attributes not working from a unit test

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, autofac

During execution as an Asp.Net Mvc application, property injection by autofac works successfully, as documented here:

http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Mvc3Integration#Filter_Attribute_Property_Injection

If I carry this same logic through to a (nunit) unit test, the properties are not being injected on my custom attribute.  Is there something specific in the mvc extensions that would cause this not to work from a unit test?

Thanks

Comment: Why u worried about DI at unit testing? You can directly set the dependencies of the filter from unit testing code right?

Answer (score 3):

**Filter attribute property injection works as part of the MVC/ASP.NET pipeline**, not as something available as a standalone feature.

You'll probably notice that the **filters on an MVC controller don't actually execute during unit tests** either. For example, put the HandleErrorAttribute on your controller action and throw an exception from that action in a unit test. Notice how the HandleErrorAttribute didn't get invoked to try to send you to the error view?

This is because **in a unit test scenario, you're not in the MVC pipeline** - you're testing controllers/actions as POCO (Plain Old CLR Objects). You won't get model binding, filters, HttpModules, or anything else that you'd normally see as part of real integration/execution.

**That's not an error, that's by design.** It's similar to the way you can unit test WCF service implementations and if you attach behaviors to them via your web.config you won't see those behaviors in the unit test. Your unit test isn't executing in the pipeline, it's executing only against the one class as a standalone entity.

**If you need to test how the whole thing works together with filters and all - *an integration test*** - you'll need to look into retrieving the content from a running version of your web application using browser automation or some other programmatic web client mechanism. For the pipeline to be in place, you have to actually be running in a real, full runtime, not in a standard/standalone unit test environment.

**As far as whether it's OK to use DI in unit tests or not... that's more a personal preference.** I use it in some of my tests, but when I do, I wire up mocks/stubs as the dependencies so I can control the interaction between my system under test and its dependencies. You don't need DI to do that. You could just construct all the fake dependencies manually and poke them in without any DI/IoC container at all. That said, in a unit test environment, you shouldn't be wiring up The Real Dependencies because then you're not testing your class as a unit - that's an integration test.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using DI for unit testing. Unit testing is all about testing the functionalities of the a particular piece of code and not others. In your case if you are testing the custom attribute then you should set the dependencies directly without relying on any IoC container to do that.

Most of the cases the dependencies would be replaced by mock objects instead of the real ones.

Comment: Personally, I prefer using my DI container in my automated tests for a couple reasons. 1. Then I'm testing my DI is wired up correctly. 2. Tests look cleaner because they're focused on execution and not composition. 3. I typically am more interested in testing all the pieces work correctly together than each piece working correctly on it's own.

Comment: Maybe. Anymore, when I hear a dev say "unit test," I assume they mean the more general "automated test," and not a true unit test.

Comment: unit testing is about only testing the class in context and not about the dependencies and other stuff http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292197(v=vs.71).aspx. Unit tests can be automated but it doesn't mean unit tests are automated tests.